# There is no audio output from pygame. (Windows 10)

Tags: python, pygame

There is no sound from pygame at all. I've tried many codes my there is only one that's working, but I don't want to create a new window.

Does anyone know why the third method is the only one that working?

These are the codes that I've tried. :

```
import os
import pygame

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(24000, 16, 2, 4096)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

person_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("person.wav")
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(person_sound)
```

```
import os
import pygame

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(24000, 16, 2, 4096)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

person_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("person.wav")
play = person_sound.play()
while play.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

here is the working one :

```
WAVFILE = 'person.wav'
import os
import pygame
import sys

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(24000, 16, 2, 4096)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
while True:
    s = pygame.mixer.Sound(WAVFILE)
    ch = s.play()
    while ch.get_busy():
        pygame.time.delay(100)
    exit()
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) from your code. It seems to conflict with [`pygame.mixer.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init).

```py
import os
import pygame

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(24000, 16, 2, 4096)

# Remove pygame.init()
# pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

person_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("person.wav")
s = pygame.mixer.Sound.play(person_sound)

# Also make sure to include this to make sure it doesn't quit immediately
while s.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

*Tested on Windows 10, Pygame 1.9.5, Python 3.7.2*